# JAVA HttpPost enctype = "multiform/data"

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httpclient

i'm trying to simulate a HttpPost request for form submission using `HttpClient 4.2.3`

the form is similar to

```
<form action="localhost/xyz.aspx" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="name">
     <input type="text" name="age">
     <input type="text" name="submit">
</form>
```

When i tried using java code like,

```
 List<NameValuePair> formparams1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 formparams1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","john"));
 formparams1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", "10"));
 UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams1);
 entity.setContentEncoding("multipart/form-data");
 entity.setContentType("multipart/form-data;boundary=--asd123");
```

i receive  **HTTP Status 400 - java.lang.RuntimeException: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part**

Also i searched a while and tried another way,

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("name",new StringBody("john",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
entity.addPart("age", new StringBody("10",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Still i get an error like **HTTP 415 HTTP 400**

Could anyone pls help me in simulating such a request.

TIA

Comment: This question could be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304663/apache-httpclient-making-multipart-form-post

Comment: @Andremoniy i have exactly tried the same and it results in **No Content-Disposition found in part** If possible u can even help on that. TIA

Answer (score 1):

The multipart entity that you are sending needs two objects to be set `FileBody` and `StringBody`. What you are setting is only `StringBody`.

In short Multipart requests generally consists of files. The server needs the file name (set using `StringBody`) and file contents (set using `FileBody`).

For example.

```
FileBody name = new FileBody(new File(fileName));
StringBody content = new StringBody("Filename: " + fileName);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("name", bin);
reqEntity.addPart("content", content);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

In your case, you dont seem to be sending any mutlipart contents. I am not sure by are using that encoding type!

Comment: i dont have to send any file content. i just reverse engineering jBPM console. so i have to simulate the same request. Could u pls elaborate if i'm wrong.

Comment: Simply remove the multipart related stuff from your code and check if thats working.

Comment: @Santhosh i'm actually trying to the same thing. https://community.jboss.org/thread/203492?start=0&tstart=0