# Upload an image AND send text with $_POST through an android app

Tags: php, android, post, httprequest, image-uploading

I have to upload an image to my server but also send some text. This is what Ive done, but it doesn't work:

```
String  UploadImage(Bitmap bm) {
    String resp = null;
    try {  
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("myserver.com/add.php");
        String rndName =generateSessionKey(15);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename",rndName));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
        form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair);
        form.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
        try {
            postRequest.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,"UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,rndName+".jpg");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", bab);
        //reqEntity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody("sfsdfsdf"));
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
        resp=s.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception here
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
    }
    return resp;
}
```

The server doesnt get `filename` and `email`.

Why doesn't it work?

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not combine UrlEncoded and Multipart. Instead, add all string fields as it own part of a Multipart.

Look here for an example:
[Apache HttpClient making multipart form post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304663/apache-httpclient-making-multipart-form-post)