# How can I get a custom Content-Disposition line using Apache httpclient?

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304663/apache-httpclient-making-multipart-form-post) to try to make a `POST` request with a data upload, but I have unusual requirements from the server-side. The server is a PHP script which requires a `filename` on the `Content-Disposition` line, because it is expecting a file upload.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="-"
```

However, on the client side, I would like to post an in-memory buffer (in this case a String) instead of a file, but have the server process it as though it were a file upload.

However, using `StringBody` I cannot add the required `filename` field on the `Content-Disposition` line. Thus, I tried to use `FormBodyPart`, but that just put the `filename` on a separate line.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody body = new StringBody(data,                              
         org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
FormBodyPart fbp = new FormBodyPart("file", body); 
fbp.addField("filename", "-");                     
entity.addPart(fbp);                               
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

How can I get a `filename` into the `Content-Disposition` line, without first writing my `String` into a file and then reading it back out again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
StringBody stuff = new StringBody("stuff");
FormBodyPart customBodyPart = new FormBodyPart("file", stuff) {

    @Override
    protected void generateContentDisp(final ContentBody body) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        buffer.append("form-data; name=\"");
        buffer.append(getName());
        buffer.append("\"");
        buffer.append("; filename=\"-\"");
        addField(MIME.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, buffer.toString());
    }

};
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart(customBodyPart);
```

Comment: `MultipartEntity` deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

As a cleaner alternative to creating an extra anonymous inner class and adding side effects to protected methods, use `FormBodyPartBuilder`:

```
StringBody stuff = new StringBody("stuff");

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append("form-data; name=\"");
    buffer.append(getName());
    buffer.append("\"");
    buffer.append("; filename=\"-\"");
String contentDisposition = buffer.toString();

FormBodyPartBuilder partBuilder = FormBodyPartBuilder.create("file", stuff);
partBuilder.setField(MIME.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition);

FormBodyPart fbp = partBuilder.build();
```

Comment: how to use above code with `MultipartEntityBuilder`?

Comment: @LeiYang I'm not sure, but you could try using the above code to build a `FormBodyPart` and then adding it to the `MultipartEntityBuilder` with [`addPart()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html#addPart(org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart)).