# How convert curl call into java HttpPostcall

Tags: java, curl, http-headers

I  have curl command:

```
curl -k -f  --header "Authorization: bearer cb084803-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2a275e112c38 " 
--header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" 
--header "X-PartnerUserId:login01" 
--form "title=fileName" 
--form "tag=mytag" 
--form "archive=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf" 
-X POST https://api.EXAMPLEAPI.com/api/v2.0/doc
```

And I want to create HTTP Request in Java API which will do the same thing
But i don't know how can'i do for the param (--form ....)

```
    Map<String, String> mapResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String resourceURL = config.getProperty(OAuthConstants.RESOURCE_SERVER_URL_UPLOAD);
    OAuth2Details oauthDetails = createOAuthDetails(config);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(resourceURL);
    httpPost.setHeader(OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION, getAuthorizationHeaderForAccessToken(oauthDetails.getAccessToken()));
    httpPost.setHeader(OAuthConstants.CONTENTE_TYPE, OAuthConstants.ENCODED_CONTENT_DATA);
    httpPost.setHeader(OAuthConstants.PARTNERUSERID, login);
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    httpPost.set...  // add: --form "title=fileName" 
    httpPost.set...  // add: --form "tag=mytag" 
    httpPost.set...  // add: --form "archive=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf" 
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    int code = -1;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304663/apache-httpclient-making-multipart-form-post

Comment: thanks Brett. but this solution does not working for me

Comment: Http error: 500 Internal error od Servlet
I do like this:
List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(OAuthConstants.PARTNERUSERID, doc.getTitre()));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

Comment: Please show your updated code. Also provide the failure from the server if available.