# POSTing to HTTPS in Java, weird behaviour

Tags: java, php, curl

I decided to POST some stuff with Java but got stuck on such a seemingly trivial task. Then I got frustrated and rewrote the whole thing in php, and it works flawlessly. I tried comparing the outputs of both Java and PHP results, and what I notice that Curl sets **Content-Type: multipart/form-data;**  whereas Java (correctly?) sets it to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded;** but this triggers **500 internal server error**. What the hell is going on?

Java debug:

```
2017/12/11 19:10:36:236 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InJJRjdORWdzUVcwQVZMR2l2WnNHUWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZVFSc0V5MCtURFE4dTZHZGlwVXdna0VGMGZtNzh0aEF4eXJcL0ZcL3d6QWM4NVdJejJaeEptUDFcL0ZDeXBEOGlDMTltbEQ4cFg0c1wvK3h4Nkp3VEhJTmFRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIzNmRjZGNmZGNmYTFkYTQzODQ2NjFkZWY3ZWVlZGJmNzBiNDFhNTQwNDU3ODAzMTA4MGNhYWRiY2VhNDU2ZmU2In0%3D;laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImF3cGg2TUFvWm54b3J4Nml5NnlBYlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC85ZzdJS2drRWxlWGExXC93bHFVNXRtTmFtTmcyblJ4cXY4eUhCY2toaWJGaFBcL2NjQllKekVrUWFvblhydWtSeHpySm4yWGlWbHE3Y3dXZjFxd3lXV3c9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjRlNGZiMjU4NDRmMWVjZjc1YzExYWM4ZjJlMTUyNzI0ZTY3NTAwYTUyZTdlNTdiZmQ2ZDg1NTk1OGE4OGQ3ZGMifQ%3D%3D[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 146[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: xxx[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:243 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:244 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "username=jnfjkwejf&_token=ZTE8t5XDf2vmBcAWpSenELkEtqvhIp9FBSy0E1Ez&domain=xxx&password=qweqweqwe&password_confirmation=qweqweqwe&captcha=U8Aq3"
2017/12/11 19:10:36:319 EET [DEBUG] wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
```

---

Java code:

```
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("xxx", 443, "https");
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2", "SSLv3" }, null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                .register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .build();
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);

    CloseableHttpClient httpsclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<>();
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "jnfjkwejf"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_token", _token));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("domain", "xxx"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "qweqweqwe"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_confirmation", "qweqweqwe"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("captcha", captcha));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, Consts.UTF_8);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("/auth/register");
    String fullCookie =
            captchaConn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie").get(1).split(";")[0] + ";" +
            captchaConn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie").get(0).split(";")[0];
    httppost.addHeader("Cookie", fullCookie);
    httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0");
    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    CloseableHttpResponse execute = httpsclient.execute(httppost);
```

PHP:

```
> POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
Accept: */*
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Im4zSXNHanBpM1FmXC9oZ0dEeFZFbElRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Inh2S2FKSktQMGFxREMwVU5KZHkzSVEzaXFyVnNWdEpiQ1IzVFd4Y3c3RWFxQXV6YXFRaFNuQlBSU2M5bEs5azh2dG9zSjFoQWlNVW00dGgzeW1IeFhRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI4MTUwZTk3ZDNkZDMyOTkxMjRkNjRhY2I5MjEzMDZmNTk5NzUwYjA5NDY3YmY0OWQ4YzQ1NmMxNTVjZDIwNzNkIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IldnbGd1STlUSVZXc0NFbWZLTVhGZEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRDBndzlSZFJLUlZHYWdJWmppZmNCOWRYV2liNnV1NFJkMzNoNEpyVGRBaXlEUm94MzNSbmZ4YVdDeHM0OTNNa21qZmQ1Tjd4UVJrK2pYS3BUQUhsbFE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImZkNTBmZjYxOTc0ZmUxNzIzZTNlOTBkYWJmMzBkODhkODkxNTk1Mjc5Nzg5MTI5NmJkYzJlYzBjOTEyMGM0OTUifQ%3D%3D
Content-Length: 718
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------e939a893b45ae97c

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache
...
```

---

Curl options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxx/auth/register');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . '.\cookiejar');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ . '.\cookiejar');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
```

Comment: Using HttpPost with no configuration to send a HTTPS request seems suspicious.

Comment: Tried replicating this request in RESTClient 3.6.1 and I also get internal server error here.

Comment: How about checking what the server error on the server says? Should give a good clue.

Comment: Cookie header looks incorrect in java case, missing a space after ';'. Updated my answer with this point.

Comment: Unless you provide us with the hostname or the server log, we can not actually help you. What we can do is just guess. Least you can do is to install Wireshark or Fiddler and show us what happens with both requests.

Answer (score 5):

If your server is expecting  `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, then you should use `MultipartEntityBuilder` instead of `UrlEncodedFormEntity`.

Your entity creation code could be something like

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder
    .create()
    .addTextBody("username", "jnfjkwejf")
    .addTextBody("_token", _token)
    .addTextBody("domain", "xxx")
    .addTextBody("password", "qweqweqwe")
    .addTextBody("password_confirmation", "qweqweqwe")
    .addTextBody("captcha", captcha)
    .build();
```

Refer this link for more details. [Apache HttpClient making multipart form post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304663/apache-httpclient-making-multipart-form-post)

**Update - One more point.**

Your cookie header does not look to be correct in Java case. The cookie pairs should be separated by a semi-colon and a space (`'; '`). space is missing in your java case. Ref - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie

Comment: Can you provide exception trace that you are getting at the server side?

Comment: I wish I had the access. :( Wrote to the owner, but no response yet.

Comment: Cookie header looks incorrect in java case, missing a space after ';'. Updated my answer with this point.

Answer (score 2):

curl can use any of the two encodings, just like php or java, it is simply a matter of configuring the request type correctly.

urlencoded is old style multipart is the new kid on the block, java must be capable of generating both, perhaps finding a new java example?

Also, why not try building the actual request yourself and send the actual bytes you need to send, by creating the request yourself byte per byte?
consider it a learning exercise.

In order to debug why the server sends 500 errors, I recommend you read your server's source code and also read your server's logs, it may only like the new way of doing stuff.

btw I like the old way, i like the simple. it used to be simple, an POST request, back in my day...
now, the new way, feels wasteful, too many bytes, too few data.

Comment: I did that, caught the php request through the wireshark and replicated it in java.. no good. I'm thinking there must be something wrong with java's https/ssl.

Comment: Consider using Apache's libraries for HTTPS