# Apache HttpClient. How to properly produce multipart requests with Encoding

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

Similar to the already existing question [Apache HttpClient making multipart form post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304663/apache-httpclient-making-multipart-form-post)

want to produce a http request, holding a file and a key=val pair.

Currently the code looks like:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/mainform.cgi/auto_config.htm");

HttpEntity ent = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addTextBody("TYPE", "6",ContentType.TEXT_BINARY)
        .addBinaryBody("upname", new File("factory.cfg"),ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,"factory.cfg")
        .build();
```

This is simply applied to HttpPost object as entity and passed to the client.

Which is sent to a linux-type device (blackbox) with a lighthttp service running. The problem is that when I send this request I do not see a response from the device(physical, and the HttpEntity always returns a default 200 OK).

Through Wireshark I've noticed two differences, on which i would really appreciate to get some help:
1. The multipart elements have an additional header(comparing to the original request) - Content-transfer-encoding, which i assume may be the reason of the fail.
2. Content length differs drastically.

So the first question would be - how to deal with the Encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the point, on which it was failing. Needed this addition:

```
.addTextBody("TYPE", "6",ContentType.WILDCARD)
.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE).setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```